# Insert a populated map into a template bst

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, binary-search-tree

So basically i am trying to populate my template binary search tree (BST) with a bunch of different maps of type:

```
    typedef map<int, map<int, vector<WeatherLogObject>>> typeMap;.
```

Currently this map will contain a bunch of years and for each year i want to create a node and insert it into the bst. Currently im having issue with this and im getting errors that i dont understand so any guidance would be greatly accepted

My BST currently contains a Node struct which contains T data and two ptrs left and right.

Currently the code i have is this i know its in my main which isnt good i plan on moving it when i get this problem fixed

```
    int main()
    {
string filePaths[125];
int counter = 0;
ifstream infile;
WeatherLog weatherLogType;
WeatherLog weatherLogTypeTemp;
vector<WeatherLog> weather;
string temp;
WeatherLog tempType;
typeMap dataMap;


infile.open("data/met_index.txt");
while (infile.peek() != EOF)
{
    infile >> filePaths[counter++];
}
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    infile.close();
    infile.clear();
    infile.open("data/" + filePaths[i]);
    getline(infile, temp, '\n');
    int getYear = 0;
    vector<WeatherLog> tempVector;
    int temp = 1;

    while (infile.peek() != EOF)
    {
        //get weatherlog object
        infile >> weatherLogType;
        //if its first object create map with new year
        if (getYear != weatherLogType.d.GetYear())
        {
            //for files with two months add the 12th month
            if (tempVector.empty())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                dataMap[tempVector[0].d.GetYear()][tempVector[0].d.GetMonth()] = tempVector;
                tempVector.clear();
            }
            getYear = weatherLogType.d.GetYear();
            temp = weatherLogType.d.GetMonth();
        }
        if(getYear == weatherLogType.d.GetYear()) // populate existing vector
        {
            if (temp == 12 && weatherLogType.d.GetMonth() == 1)
            {
                temp = 1;
            }
            if (temp == weatherLogType.d.GetMonth())
            {
                tempVector.push_back(weatherLogType);
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if last month is getting inputted
                if (tempVector.empty())
                {
                    temp++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataMap[tempVector[0].d.GetYear()][tempVector[0].d.GetMonth()] = tempVector;
                    tempVector.clear();
                    temp++;
                }


            }

        }
        //Add Node for each year into bst
    }

    dataMap[tempVector[0].d.GetYear()][tempVector[0].d.GetMonth()] = tempVector;
    tempVector.clear();
}
int mid, max, year;
max = dataMap.size();
mid = max / 2;
TBST<typeMap> tree;
typeMap tempMap;
for (typeMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.begin(); it != dataMap.end(); ++it)
{
    tempMap[it->first] = it->second;
    tree.Insert(tempMap);
    tempMap.clear();
}
```

}

So by the end id like to be able to add the map to the bst starting in the middle so i can get optimal search speeds and the bst has the correct format but currently i am getting these errors.

```
    Error   C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found  Simple Read Date    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility    1108    

    Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'   Simple Read Date    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility    1108
```

Sorry if perhaps i havent added enough information please do let me know and ill update as soon as possible

Comment: Can you transform it into a [mcve] so we can try it out?

Comment: Maybe i should have mentioned all my data is being read in from a bunch of files so i dont know if i could recreate a working version for you but basically it will read from files which will populate a bunch of vectors with one months data. put that vector in the dataMap. location based on vector month and year

Comment: @Snake2034 *so i dont know if i could recreate a working version for you* -- Any compiler error can be recreated with just a dummy set of classes / functions and some do-nothing code that calls uses those classes and functions.  It doesn't matter if those functions do nonsense, as long as the compiler error is reproduced.  So mentioning reading data from files is a moot point.

Comment: [Start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aabcc23a3dd1b7ae).  Now it doesn't matter if `Weather...` is empty.  That is irrelevant.  Add dummy code to this to duplicate the error.

Comment: [And here is an incremental change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53d946c19839beca).  These are the things you should be doing to duplicate the error.  So what goes in `foo` that duplicates the compiler error?  It doesn't need to read files, get data from the keyboard, etc.

Comment: @Snake2034 [More changes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb01ad7f3c24d4f6).  At this point, you should take the code you see at the link, and fill in `Insert` with the *minimal* set of code that reproduces the error.  So far, no error is given, and note -- it doesn't matter if there is data or not -- the compiler doesn't care -- all it's looking at is *syntax*.

Comment: Ok i think ive managed to add what you are after in that last one you sent. there is a massive error going on there now

Comment: i can tell you that when i remove that like of code that inserts into the tree my program works fine

Comment: @Snake2034 Please post the code, since there is [still no error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a5d5a0f776fe2e3), given your description.  Whatever the error is, the type you're giving your BST violates some prerequisite condition required of that type that you are not aware of.   What in the Insert() requires `std::less<>`? (this is in the error message).  Are you sorting something and the type isn't sortable, or doing some equivalent operation like sorting?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88714b6871b8f067 i wasnt able to reproduce the error as idk whats causing it in the first place

Comment: Turns out all i needed was overloaded operators in the class i was doing this in but thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Snake2034 Now we need a separate discussion on the right way to overload operators.  There is no need to rewrite the `operator >` from scratch if if you have already written `operator <`.  You write `operator >` in terms of `operator <`, i.e. `operator > (a, b)` is nothing more than `return (b < a);`

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b449cfe812312a81).  You've also seem to confuse `operator=` with `operator==`, as you seemed to have written the former when you meant the latter. You can also derive the other operators from `operator <`.  I leave it as an exercise.

Comment: @Snake2034 This question is still listed as unanswered. Do you need more guidance than what Paul has given? "_i wasnt able to reproduce the error as idk whats causing it in the first place_" indicates that the question is best removed.